# redirect omniauth-facebook to a specific page after authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

Newbie here , i have omniauth-facebook setup in an application , every thing working fine , my only issue i want to redirect to another page after the authentication ,but i can't quite figure it out . 
 my first solution was to add a route to match the auth/facebook/callback to "sessions#new " it's not working . other thing i try is to add a redirect in the controller , not working also , what is the proper to redirect to a specific page ?

controller

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
    def facebook
    # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
    @user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect , :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "sign in successfuly") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
end
```

routes

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
```

thanks for any help .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When your get user by `find_for_facebook_oauth` method then you can login with that user and use redirect_to for your desired path. You can do something like:

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
    def facebook
    # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
    @user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in(@user)
      redirect_to desired_path, notice: 'Signed in successfully.'
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "sign in successfuly") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I have this controller you have mentioned then also I am being redirected to http://localhost:8000/auth/facebook/callback#_=_
I am using api-only Rails 5 app with devise-token-auth, omniauth-facebook and Devise